# Let α1 , …, αr be distinct even permutations, and β an odd permutation. Show then α1β, …, αr β are r distinct odd permutations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, permutations, parity

> Q: Let $\alpha_1 , …, \alpha_r$ be distinct even permutations, and $\beta$ an odd permutation. Show then $\alpha_1\beta, …, \alpha_r \beta$ are $r$ distinct odd permutations.

> Proof: $\alpha_i$ can be written as a product of $2k$ transpositions, $\beta$
> can be written as a product of $m$ odd transpositions,
> $\implies\alpha_i\beta$ can be written as a product of $2k+m$
> transpositions, which is odd, this implies that $\alpha_i\beta$ is
> odd.
>
> Now $\alpha_i\beta$ is distinct because of the fact that
> $\alpha_i\beta$ is equivalent to $\alpha_i$ over a different domain,
> that is the domain $\{(\beta(1),\cdots,\beta(n)\}$, and since all
> $\alpha_i$ are distinct, this implies that $\alpha_i\beta$ is distinct
> aswell

Is this proof good? I ask not because I struggle to write this proof, I'm actually fairly confident it is correct, I am just asking because I am a self-studying and have no mentorship in proof writing, so I've sort of just tried to pick it up along the way.
Can I please have some tips as to how I could have done better on this proof? Or if it's okay already, please tell me as I am operating in the dark when it comes to these new textbooks I am using that do not have answers at all!

> REVISED PROOF: $\alpha_i$ is written as a product of $2k$
> transpositions, $\beta$ a product of $2m+1$ transpositions, $\implies$
> $\alpha_i\beta$ is written as a product of $2k+2m+1=2(k+m)+1$
> transpositions, which is odd $\implies \alpha_i\beta$ is odd.
> $\alpha_i\beta$ is distinct by the fact that $\alpha_i$ is distinct
> $\forall i$ and $\beta$ is constant.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think the proof could be more formalized, especially the second part: for instance, you can write that $\alpha_i\neq\alpha_j\implies\alpha_i\beta\neq\alpha_j\beta$ (for $i\neq j$) by claiming that the contraposition is obvious. For the first part, I would have used the signature morphism: $\epsilon(\alpha_i\beta)=\epsilon(\alpha_i)\epsilon(\beta)=1\cdot(-1)=-1$.

Comment: "$m$ odd transpositions" is a weird way to write it - "odd" here, in English, would apply to transposition rather than $m.$ Just write $2m+1$ for the odd number.

Comment: This is really two different unrelated statements: (1) If $\alpha_i\neq\alpha_j$ then $\alpha_i\beta\neq \alpha_j\beta.$ This would be true in any group, and doesn't need even and odd permutations. (2) If $\alpha$ is an even permutation and $\beta$ is an odd permutation then $\alpha\beta$ is an odd permutation.

Comment: @nejimban I'm not sure if @'ing you is appropriate, thanks for the welcome! I do not know what a signature morphism is? I now see that the second part is obvious and could be proved way more succinctly, thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have revised the proof and edited the post. How can I upvote you for your help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Regarding the signature morphism, you may want to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation). But your proof is totally fine.

Comment: Your proof with domains doesn’t really make sense. Just to keep it simple, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both just swap 1 and 2, then $\alpha \beta$ isn’t switching 2 and 1 but rather is the identity. Instead, you can just apply the inverse to show the contra positive (a1 b=a2 b leads to a1=a1 b b^-1= a2 b b^-1 =a2)

Comment: As another example? If there were functions, if b(x)=0 and a1(x)=x and a2(x)=2x, then a1 b=0=a2 b. Your “domain” argument would apply equally well here. You need to use the fact that b is invertible somehow (either directly or by noting that it’s surjective).

Comment: @Eric Oh wow lol now just applying the inverse of beta seems super obvious... I guess sometimes I overcomplicate things in my head when speaking in terms of permutations because they're slightly new to me. Thanks for the help